I'm completely new to coding and renpy is testing me in ways I've never been tested
ok so I'm trying to give the player the option to pick multiple choices and the ones they choose I'll flag to use later in the game. But I don't want them picking the same option multiple times so I'm trying to say if it's flagged as true don't show the option again but idk it's not working. help?
Ive also tried flagging the original menu items as false but I just cant figure it out
Here's the code
menu:
"a soda cap themed bottle opener":
$ bottle_open = True
jump boo
"fidget cube":
$ fidget = True
jump boo
"A bedazzled pepper spray can":
$ pepper = True
jump boo
"A tactical pocket knife (the knife part is broken)":
$ knife = True
jump boo
"A mini-figure of your favorite psychologist":
$ freud = True
jump boo
label boo:
"and"
label keys:
menu:
"A soda cap themed bottle opener" if bottle_open = False:
$ bottle_open1 = True
jump leave
"fidget cube" if fidget = False:
$ fidget1 = True
jump leave
"A bedazzled pepper spray can" if pepper = False:
$ pepper1 = True
jump leave
"A tactical pocket knife (the knife part is broken)" if knife = False:
$ knife1 = True
jump leave
"A mini-figure of your favorite psychologist" if freud = False:
$ freud1 = True
jump leave
label leave:

Hm it looks like there might be a few issues, I don't know if things are sending funny thanks to copy pasting to here, this is my first time posting here but...
here is a menu from one of my test games
menu :
    "What would you like to make?"
    "Go Collect Materials":
        jump materialcollect

    "Spear" if "Rock" and "Stick" in items:
        $ items.append("Spear")
        "You've made a spear!"
        $ items.remove("Rock")
        $ items.remove("Stick")

    "Axe" if "Rock" and "Stick" in items:
        $ items.append("Axe")
        "you've made an Axe!"
        $ items.remove("Rock")
        $ items.remove("Stick")
    "hammer" if "Rock" and "Stick" in items:
        $ items.append("Hammer")
        "you've made a Hammer!"
        $ items.remove("Rock")
        $ items.remove("Stick")

    "HammerAxe" if "Axe" and "Hammer" in items:
        $ items.append("HammerAxe")
        $ items.remove("Hammer")
        $ items.remove("Axe")
        "youve made the Hammer Axe! you sucessfully combined two items!"

now look at this
notice first that the ":" is at the very end after your variable and that you have to make sure its indented properly
also you could define it as this if youre checking whats in a list
BUT in your case you'd probably write it a bit differently
so heres my code
    "Axe" if "Rock" and "Stick" in items:
        $ items.append("Axe")
        "you've made an Axe!"
        $ items.remove("Rock")
        $ items.remove("Stick")

and heres how i'd write yours
menu:
"a soda cap themed bottle opener" if bottle_open == True:
jump boo
(note: the double equal sign is used for checking if something is equal!)
(Singular is for changing the variable! if i remember correctly)
Which by the way means you can do things like if bottle_open != True: it will read it as "if bottle_open ISINT True" (the exclamation mark next to the equal sign is checking if its NOT equal) that's why its important that the double equal sign is used, so you can define it more freely
on that note you can also do >= and <=    to ask is it greater than or equal to a number when using numbers!
Also it looks to me like you might be trying to make a sort of inventory like thing
in which case you might want to make a list  by using
default items = []
then using $ items.append("Spear") and $ items.remove("Stick") (as examples) to add and remove things from your inventory (like i showed here) so that you can check if something is in the inventory (you can see how to do that by looking at my code above) or not when you need to use the items.
Also the option will only show up if the conditions are fulfilled
